# Select buttons while sliding on screen Flash CS6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm working on a Cs6 android Air project and i have about 100 buttons that i use as letters.

[image]

Each of these buttons have an EventListener.

By clicking i store the value of each btn to an Array creating strings of letters.

Is there any way to select buttons when i slide my finger over the screen instead of clicking?

Answer (score 0):

Back to basics, the mouse over and mouse out events you could use touch and multi-touch events instead.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TouchEvent.html